Json aggregate on Mariadb Sql
Im using 10.11.8-MariaDB on server.
Here db table schema;



id
productid
date
stone
wood




78
113
1721638800
[{"id":"2","spend":"17,62","cost":"368,557"},{"id":"3","spend":"1,73","cost":"36,186"}]
[{"id":"2","spend":"60,62","cost":"1303,330"}]


79
113
1721638800
[{"id":"2","spend":"16,62","cost":"360,557"},{"id":"3","spend":"1,73","cost":"36,186"}]
[{"id":"2","spend":"60,62","cost":"1303,330"}]


80
117
1721811600
[{"id":"4","spend":"5,62","cost":"150,557"}]
[{"id":"4","spend":"0","cost":"0"}]



Im using this sample sql codes;
SELECT 
  e.productid,
  h.id AS stone_id,
  SUM(CAST(REPLACE(h.spend, ',', '.') AS DECIMAL(20, 6))) AS stone_spend,
  SUM(CAST(REPLACE(h.cost, ',', '.') AS DECIMAL(20, 6))) AS stone_cost,
  h2.id AS wood_id,
  SUM(CAST(REPLACE(h2.spend, ',', '.') AS DECIMAL(20, 6))) AS wood_spend,
  SUM(CAST(REPLACE(h2.cost, ',', '.') AS DECIMAL(20, 6))) AS wood_cost
FROM 
  production e
  LEFT JOIN JSON_TABLE(
    IFNULL(NULLIF(e.stone, ''), '[]'),
    '$[*]' COLUMNS (
      id INT PATH '$.id',
      spend VARCHAR(20) PATH '$.spend',
      cost VARCHAR(20) PATH '$.cost'
    )
  ) AS h ON 1=1
  LEFT JOIN JSON_TABLE(
    IFNULL(NULLIF(e.wood, ''), '[]'),
    '$[*]' COLUMNS (
      id INT PATH '$.id',
      spend VARCHAR(20) PATH '$.spend',
      cost VARCHAR(20) PATH '$.cost'
    )
  ) AS h2 ON h.id = h2.id
WHERE 
  e.date BETWEEN '$first' AND '$last'
GROUP BY 
  e.productid, h.id, h2.id;

My php codes working but The grand total is being made. What I want to do is separate expenses and costs based on ID.
I want aggregate on sql. If they have the same date and product id, grouping the id in the json and adding the spend and cost should give the following result;
[
  {
    "productid": "113",
    "date": "1721638800",
    "stone": [
      {
        "id": "2",
        "spend": "34,24",
        "cost": "729,114"
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "spend": "3,46",
        "cost": "72,372"
      }
    ],
    "wood": [
      {
        "id": "2",
        "spend": "121,24",
        "cost": "2606,66"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "productid": "117",
    "date": "1721638800",
    "stone": [
      {
        "id": "4",
        "spend": "5,62",
        "cost": "150,557"
      }
    ],
    "wood": [
      {
        "id": "4",
        "spend": "0",
        "cost": "0"
      }
    ]
  }
]

-UPDATE-
Latest sql codes:
SELECT 
  u.productid,
  COUNT(DISTINCT u.uid) AS counttotal,
  u.date,
  CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(
    JSON_OBJECT(
      'id', u.hjid,
      'spend', u.spend,
      'cost', u.cost
    )
  ), ']') AS stone
FROM (
  SELECT 
    u.productid,
    u.date,
    u.uid,
    u.hjid,
    SUM(u.spend) AS spend,
    SUM(u.cost) AS cost
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      u.productid,
      u.date,
      u.id AS uid,
      JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(u.stone, CONCAT('$[', jt.idx, '].id'))) AS hjid,
      CAST(REPLACE(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(u.stone, CONCAT('$[', jt.idx, '].spend'))), ',', '.') AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS spend,
      CAST(REPLACE(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(u.stone, CONCAT('$[', jt.idx, '].cost'))), ',', '.') AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS cost
    FROM production u
    JOIN JSON_TABLE(
      u.stone,
      '$[*]' COLUMNS (idx FOR ORDINALITY)
    ) AS jt
    WHERE u.date BETWEEN 1719781200 AND 1722459599
    AND JSON_VALID(u.stone) = 1
  ) AS u
  WHERE u.hjid IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY u.productid, u.date, u.uid, u.hjid
) AS u
GROUP BY u.productid;

Result;
[{"id": null, "spend": 0, "cost": 0},{"id": "4", "spend": 0, "cost": 0},{"id": "5", "spend": 0, "cost": 0},{"id": "6", "spend": 0, "cost": 0},{"id": "7", "spend": 0, "cost": 0}]

Where my mistake?

This is not PHP, this is SQL

I do see different values, where is my mistake.... , see: https://dbfiddle.uk/iSlw51mZ

You should start to normalize your input data, and have a column named spend and a column named costs. Then this is a basic SQL question, because converting the result back to JSON is also asked/answered on stackoverflow multiple times.

@Luuk Thank you for answer. There are multiple different IDs for each record in the JSON inside the stone column. The spent and cost values ​​of each ID are different from each other. Breaking and collecting the data in PHP causes excessive time. It is much faster to collect and organize the JSON by grouping by product ID in SQL.

The results from your innermost sub-select are incorrect. See details, i even disabled the grouping, and just 1 record is showing: https://dbfiddle.uk/Aix05R2i
